# Geolocation, Accuracy and Affine Transformation: What is causing my inaccurate conversion from a lat/long location into a point on my image

Tags: javascript, mysql, svg, geolocation, coordinate-systems

I've implemented some code to create some code to treat an image of a relatively small location like plane for converting between locations on the image I have stored and incoming Lat/Long information.

Using the formulas provided at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635757(v=vs.85).aspx I wrote these lines of code among others

```
var vector = math.matrix(
[[x1],
 [y1],
 [x2],
 [y2]]);
var matrix = math.matrix(
[[lat1,long1,1,0]
,[-long1,lat1,0,1]
,[lat2,long2,1,0]
,[-long2,lat2,0,1]]);
var solution = math.multiply(math.inv(matrix),vector);
```

There is an implicit conversion from the vector returned to solution into conversiondata as I put it into and take it back out of my database.

```
a = parseFloat(conversiondata['A']);
b = parseFloat(conversiondata['B']);
c = parseFloat(conversiondata['C']);
d = parseFloat(conversiondata['D']);
var long = position.coords.longitude;
var lat = position.coords.latitude;
var x = a * lat + b * long + c;
var y = b * lat - a * long + d;
```

The values x1, x2, y1, y2 are supplied by getting user click data.
The values lat1, lat2, long1, long2 are supplied by the user in response to two clicks on the map image.

When putting x,y back onto the map its not quite in the right position, the position on the map seems to almost be on the opposite side of the line defined by (x1,y1) and (x2,y2). I'm trying to tell what the reason for the inaccuracy is. (I am however assuming for the time being that the apparent reflection is a coincidence)

If someone could help me narrow down what could be going wrong here are things I've considered (the map doesn't reach even a mile in any direction for reference).

The affine transformation simply doesn't work - But acccording to the link provided it includes scaling so that shouldn't be the cause of the problem
There is a problem with my setting of variables - I've been looking at my code too long to see it if it is.
I am losing too much accuracy moving the var data to MySQL as a float or to PHP as a string
I am not giving accurate enough information from click data / lat/long input. - I zoomed i significantly when clicking on the map and getting the lat/long from google maps though
SVG isn't accuracte enough - Though looking at the xml data it keeps the decimals.
The area that I'm working with is too big to simplify by assuming that the local map is a flat plane

Any help is appreciated, thanks for reading this far.

For further reference I put the lat/long data that JavaScript gave me into google maps and i'm comparing accuracy to that rather than my actual location.

Additional reference: I found "landmarks" on the east and west edges of my image and have calculated the longitude difference to be 0.02695 with the length of the image being at least twice the height.

Sample values of a full run-through of values.

Reference Points

Point 1 (x,y) = (619,564)

Point 1 (lat,long) = (X.099546,-Y.465179)

Point 2 (x,y) = (1181,190)

Point 2 (lat,long) = (X.10365341,-Y.457014)

Geolocation

Predicted coordinate (x,y) = (975,262)

Given coordinate(lat,long) = (X.102851,-Y.459996)

Real Blip (x,y) = (1022.7498707999475,351.02335709985346)

Real blip (approximate lat,long) = (X.101964, -Y.459340)

(Real blip lat long is approximate as it is in a body of water with no good landmarks)

For safety's sake I've taken the digits before the decimal out of the lat/long coordinates but I can confirm that all the X's are equal and all the Y's are equal

Additionally I played with the lat long values in Chrome's developer tools, it seems like the axes are a bit rotated approximately 30 degrees from what it should be

Comment: The earth is not a 2d co-ordinate system, it's an oblate spheroid.

Comment: The areas that I intend to use this for are very small, a handful of city blocks at most. I do not believe that the drift caused by curvature should be huge unless someone could provide some reference estimating how large a drift occurs

Comment: Can you give an example with sample coordinates?

Comment: It'll take a bit, I've moved around a bit since my original question post, if you could give a more specific example of what numbers you'd like to see I'd be happy to help. For reference the coordinates you could be asking for in the lat/long space would include my reference points, my gps coordinates, the lat/long of my blip translated onto the map or more abstractly the corners of my map. In x/y space coordinates would include the two reference points again, the blip and the height/width of the image. @Salman

Comment: Just some sample coordinates, the result you are getting, and the expected results I mean.

Comment: I've added some values to work with if these aren't enough I'll redo the values on a new map that I am unaffiliated with to give full Lat/Long values and the values of A,B,C and D @Salman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After sufficient poking around I figured out that I had ordered lat and long incorrectly. On my map that has not been rotated from N at the top the following code brings me within just a few feet, more than explainable than the lack of precision resulting from relying on user input and the pixel grid.

```
var matrix = math.matrix(
[[long1,lat1,1,0]
,[-lat1,long1,0,1]
,[long2,lat2,1,0]
,[-lat2,long2,0,1]]);
```

And

```
var x = a * long + b * lat + c;
var y = b * long - a * lat + d;
```

For anyone else that is interested in pursuing this as a potential solution to simplify the math of their app
The drift that occurred was less than 40 feet over a map with a diagonal of 8000 feet and a difference in reference points of around 3000 feet. This means the drift is little over 1% of the distance of the reference points, this includes the effect of human error.

This error should decrease as you work on smaller maps and increase as you work on bigger maps.

I tested it again on a map with a ~90 degree rotation and the code held up